# Elastic Beanstalk environment variables from S3

Tags: amazon-s3, environment-variables, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

In .ebextensions, I have a file (environmentvariables.config) that looks like this:

```
commands:
  01_get_env_vars:
    command: aws s3 cp s3://elasticbeanstalk-us-east-1-466049672149/ENVVAR.sh /home/ec2-user
  02_export_vars:
    command: source /home/ec2-user/ENVVAR.sh
```

The shell script is a series of simple export key=value commands.

The file is correctly placed on the server, but it seems like it isn't being called with source. If I manually log into the app and use source /home/ec2-user/ENVVAR.sh, it sets up all my environment variables, so I know the script works.

Is it possible to set up environment variables this way? I'd like to store my configuration in S3 and automate the setup so I don't need to commit any variables to source control (option_settings) or manually enter them into the console.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: 
Active load S3 variables in Rails app to bypass environment variable issue altogether.

Put a json in S3, download to server, read ENV VAR from there in environment.rb